# Error en InputBox

Tags: vba

la linea del **inputbox** me da error en este código no se en que estoy fallando. El mensaje dice: (Error de compilación el uso de la propiedad no es valido) ,Agradezco su ayuda. El código es:

```
Private Sub Texto78_AfterUpdate()

vacia = DCount("*", "[p1]")
Dim varientri As SubForm
nro = (nro_identificacion)

If nro = "" Then
Else
  intx = DCount("*", "[p1]", "[nro_identificacion]= '" & nro & "'")

If intx = 0 Then

  varientri = InputBox("Desea introducirlo?", "No encontrado")

MsgBox varientri
If varientri = Empty Then Exit Sub

  Dim sql As String
sql = "INSERT INTO p1 (nro_identificacion) VALUES ('" & nro & "')"
  DoCmd.RunSQL sql
  DoCmd.OpenForm "afp01", , , "nro_identificacion= '" & nro & "'"
Else
  DoCmd.OpenForm "afp01", , , "nro_identificacion= '" & nro & "'"
End If
End If
```

Comment: Que tipo es subform? es de alguna libreria? `Dim varientri As SubForm`

Comment: Tienes definido `varientri` como un objeto `Subform`, pero cuando llamas al inputbox, se supone que debes devolver un texto, un booleano o un número. Y por eso te falla. Prueba a definir `varientri` como `String`, por ejemplo.